# String Encoding in java

Tags: java, string, encoding

I have a String `String a="123+>jo` I want to en
code the String so that I can redirect it to an url. I initially tried it with **urlencoder** but in urldecoder +(plus) is removed while decoding.So i lost my data.
**What is the right way to encode so that I get the same string while decoding also?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLEncoder works perfectly. The plus sign is succesfully encoded into `%2B`.

### Encoding: Works

Here is the IDEONE project:
http://ideone.com/zMDur

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;

// ...

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
            String str = "123+>jo";
            String str2 = "http://1.com/23+>jo";
            System.out.println(URLEncoder.encode(str));
            System.out.println(URLEncoder.encode(str2));
    }
```

prints:

```
123%2B%3Ejo
http%3A%2F%2F1.com%2F23%2B%3Ejo
```

### Encoding + Decoding: Works

The IDEONE project with decoding as well: http://ideone.com/Ypfv4

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

// ...

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
            String str = "123+>jo";
            String str2 = "http://1.com/23+>jo";
            System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(URLEncoder.encode(str)));
            System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(URLEncoder.encode(str2)));
    }
```

Prints:

```
123+>jo
http://1.com/23+>jo
```

---

So everything works using the `java.net.URLEncoder` and `java.net.URLDecoder`.

Comment: @Martin Courteaux Yea it works :) I made some mistake in my code. Thanks anyways. I accepted your answer. You can up my question if u wish to.

Comment: Thanks dude :). I hope more ups from you on my questions.:P LOL :)